# Container.DataItem.Row.GetChildRows Issue

Tags: asp.net

I have the following code in an aspx file that I cannot get to work:

```
<asp:repeater id="MessageRepeater" runat="server">
. . .
<asp:DataList id="CommentList" style="Z-INDEX: 112; LEFT: 14px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 520px" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Container.DataItem.Row.GetChildRows("MsgComments") %>'>
</asp:DataList>
. . .
</asp:repeater>
```

The error I receive is:

```
CS0117: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Row'
```

`MsgComments` is a relationship between two tables in my dataset that is connected to the repeater control.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, thanks in advance??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just Included the `SYSTEM.DATA` namespace in aspx design page like:

```
<@import namespace="System.Data">
```